# Can't see my app on google apps marketplace after more than one day

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I tried the following link https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing to publish my apps on google apps marketplace, but after one day, I still can't find it on google apps marketplace.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions on how to write a program to search for your app on Google Marketplace?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm actually want to know if there is any step that I didn't do correctly on above link that make my apps doesn't appear on google apps marketplace. It's said that after I published it, it will appear in the google apps marketplace.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an issue with Google Play, not a specific programming question.

Comment: Google Play? do you even read the title of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the first time you submit your app you might want to submit this review-request form in order to show on the market:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/14QOb8PbSLKDgwIp8Zv-luoAAVurPXUqtzL0Hgikp3rk/viewform

Comment: Hi MeLight, I already did that as well, but it still doesn't appear yet until now. Is that review-request will give a feedback to my developer email address? because I also didn't received any email regarding the review-request form from google. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works - but I think they should contact you if there's something wrong with the listing

Comment: Hi MeLight, it still doesn't appear on google apps marketplace. Is the setup need to be appeared to public? because I just want it to be appeared to certain users. thanks.

Comment: If you want only specific users to be able to install your app you can provide them with the direct app url

Comment: Hi MeLight, if I did that, it seems it doesn't appeared on the google apps marketplace. Maybe I still need to change it to publish it to public? thanks.